# What happens when a character with the Immanence Destiny takes Dual-Type damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage-resistance, damage-types, epic-tier

A character with the Immanence Epic Destiny has the following ability:

> **Immanence Variable Resistance (21st level):** After the first time you take damage of a particular type during an encounter, you gain resist 20 to that damage type until the end of the encounter.

Some creatures can deal "Dual Type" damage, such as "Necrotic/Cold".  This means that you must resist *both* types in order to resist this damage.

If hit by such an attack, does the Immanence character gain resist 20 to both types?  One type?  Or neither?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Both Types**

There is no listed limit to how many times Immanence can trigger in an encounter beyond once for each damage type. If you're hit by a dual-type attack, you've been hit by two damage types. Immanence Variable Resistance would trigger once for each damage type (as it's the first time you've been damaged by that type, independently), giving you resistance to both.